# Make splat optional in react-router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So currently, I want to have a route where it could be any enumeration of ids (kind of like a file browser). It looks like this:

```
<Route path="/browser">
  <IndexRoute component={FileBrowser} />
  <Route path=":id">
    <IndexRoute component={HardDriveBrowser} />
    <Route path="folders/**/:folderId" component={FolderContents} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

However, if I visit a route such as `/browser/1/folders/2`, it does not match. I think it is expecting the splat.

Is there a way to specify the splat as optional, or have it default to an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

In react-router v4, simply put `?` at the end to make the parameter optional. In react-router v2, you use parenthesis to make a parameter optional. ex: `(:folderId)` would make that optional.

Comment: You are using react router v2/3. It should be `folders/**(/:folderId)`

Comment: there's still a problem there: `splat` will always be there, but `:folderId` won't be

Comment: Looks like this path matches correctly, though: `"folders/(**/):folderId"`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what was optional and what wasnt. Either way, parenthesis make a parameter optional :)